# Weird cin behaviour

Tags: c++, oop

After some suggestions. I applied these.

Excerpt from a function `bool getInput(int format=1)`

```
cin>>num1>>plus>>num2>>i;
if(cin.fail()){
    cout<<"\n[X][cin--fail] Oops! You entered in the incorrect format! Correct format: a+bi";
    cin.clear();    
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX);

    return false;
}
if(plus == '+' && i=='i'){
    setComplex(num1, num2);
    return true;
} else {
    cout<<"\n[X] Oops! You entered in the incorrect format! Correct format: a+bi";
    return false;
}
```

I've another function which calls the above mentioned function.

```
void getInput_recursive(int format=1){
    while(!getInput(format)){};
}
```

It works fine for correct input. 
But when the input is like `2+3iiiii` then there is some weird thing happens.

My first guess: Maybe this was due to input buffer. I tried to clear it using `cin.ignore` and `cin.clear` but still nothing happened.

Can anyone help me out here? What am i doing wrong?

Please find the complete code here: http://codepad.org/Gl2zBrn1

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good, and you do the right operation but I think you have the order mixed up:
first  `cin.clear();` to reset the flags, than `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` to clear the buffer.

EDIT:

I think you need to replace `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` with `cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');`
Let me know if this does the trick.

Comment: it changed my output but it was again weird and undefined :/

Comment: can you paste in the functions get_input and get_inputRecursive...maybe the problem is not in the code you are showing

Answer (score 2):

(a) Don't recurse.  `while (!getInput(format)) {}` will do, recursion is for saving state for later resumption and there's nothing to resume here.

(b) You're not returning a value on the `false` branch

```
bool getInput_recursive(int format=1){
    if(getInput(format) == true){
        return true;
    } else {
        getInput_recursive(format);   // here
    }
}
```

and that produces undefined behavior.

and (c) I think you need to look up what

```
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

does, and what state that will leave your stream in. That'll do it.

Comment: Suggestion noted. But. I still can't see why this is undefined behaviour and why should i return a value on false branch? I see this is pretty straightforward. if input fails then it again asks for input, but if input succeeds than the function exits with true value? Isn't that it?

Comment: Did `while(!getInput(format)){}` but the same problem persists

Comment: re the UB, some digging will turn up the fact that failing to return a value from a function declared to return a value does in fact provoke undefined behavior in all its implications, as for "why", checking wikipedia and if that's not satisfactory extending the reach of your google-fu  before asking is always a good idea.